# Как с помощь команды прочитать содержимое файла в Linux?

Tags: linux, консоль

Как с помощь команды `echo` вывести содержимое текстового документа (*.txt)?

Comment: Никак. Откуда взялась такая странная задача?

Comment: Не поверите, по учебе такое задание дали, для лучшего пониманию терминала. А можно ли, допустим, ретранслировать содержимое файла так, чтобы оно стало новым именем другого файла? Всё так же на основе данной команды.

Comment: Ретранслируйте лучше всё задание со всеми граничными условиями. А то окажется, что у нас есть вся мощь bash-а, а вы об этом забыли упомянуть.

Comment: `while read l; do echo $l; done < /etc/passwd`

Comment: [cat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)?

Comment: совершенно непонятно, о чём вопрос. куда прочитать? зачем прочитать?

Comment: Прошу прощения, вопрос уже решён. Спасибо всем большое за помощь!

Comment: ага, понятно. вопрос был отредактирован, что сделало вопрос совершенно непонятным. а ответ бессмысленным. откатываю на первую версию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например, с помощью xargs:

```
xargs -n1 -d'\n' echo <foo.txt
```

На голом shell'е можно с помощью `read`, перенаправления и цикла:

```
IFS='' # дабы не терять начальные/конечные пробелы
while read s; do 
  echo "$s"
done <foo.txt
```